# Retrieving the set of tabs from a Teams Channel using Graph returns a 500 error

Tags: channel, microsoft-graph-teams

This was working but it is no longer.

Doing this from Graph Explorer:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/########-####-####-####-########/channels/19:################@thread.skype/tabs

returns:

{"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"Failed to execute request.","innerError":{"request-id":"798c78c3-cdb1-49d5-be35-046e8f82bb17","date":"2020-01-07T16:51:13"}}}

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is caused because I created a channel tab having a non-null ODataType value. This value is instantiated by default when the class is instantiated. When I POST the new tab with the non-null, the tab is created (can be seen in the UI) but returns the "Internal Error". When getting the set of tabs back the Internal Error is also returned. If ODataType is set to null when the tab is created then the channel tab REST call succeeds. Subsequent channel tab enumeration succeed without error.